# Aligning equations: equation+system of equations on the same line

Tags: equations, align

I have a line on which there are an equation and a system of equations. How can I align the equations of the system (vertical alignment of = symbols)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{sistema}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}%
{\end{array}\right.}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
TTR(t) = TTR_{PLATEAU} \left( 1 - e^{- k \, t} \right) \hspace{0.5cm} con \hspace{0.2cm} \begin{sistema}
    TTR_{PLATEAU} = \frac{ir}{R_a} \\
    k = \frac{R_a}{Q} 
  \end{sistema}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: How is the `sistema` environment defined?

Comment: Sorry @Mico, now I edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions -- see below. Speaking for myself, I'd say the first solution, which doesn't perform alignment on the `=` symbols inside the "sistema", looks better. However, there's no arguing about tastes, right? Note that both solutions typeset the material of the systems in display-stye math mode.

Either way, do take care to properly typeset variable names, such as `TTR` and `PLATEAU`. The following example provides some suggestions in this regard.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l} % left-aligned, automatic display-math style
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}

\newcommand\TTR{\textit{TTR}}
\newcommand{\PLATEAU}{\textsc{plateau}}

\newenvironment{sistema}%
   {\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
    \left\lbrace \begin{array}{L}}%
   {\end{array} \right.}

\newenvironment{sistemax}%
   {\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
    \left\lbrace \begin{array}{RCL}}%
   {\end{array} \right.}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\TTR(t) = \TTR_{\PLATEAU} ( 1 - e^{- kt}) \quad\text{con}\quad
\begin{sistema}
    \TTR_{\PLATEAU} = \frac{ir}{R_a} \\
    k = \frac{R_a}{Q} 
  \end{sistema}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\TTR(t) = \TTR_{\PLATEAU} ( 1 - e^{- kt}) \quad\text{con}\quad
\begin{sistemax}
    \TTR_{\PLATEAU} &=& \frac{ir}{R_a} \\[2.5ex] % <-- need extra space
    k &=& \frac{R_a}{Q} 
  \end{sistemax}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Who down-voted both the query as well as both my answer and the one by @Cragfelt, all within the space of a few second? And, why? Care to enlighten us?

Comment: Is there any way to know who downvoted our answers and the question?

Comment: @Cragfelt - Only the admins would know who the downvoter is. I left a note with the site admins on Sunday evening, pointing out that the query as well as two of the three answers got downvoted, all within a minute of each other. (Bernard's answer was spared, I suppose, because he didn't post it until after the downvoting vandal had done his/her "work".) I also asked the admins to look into whether this was the work of a serial downvoter and, if so, to take appropriate countermeasures. I haven't heard back from them yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to add parameter `r` in the definition of your environment `{r@{}l@{}}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{sistema}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{r@{}l@{}}}% <-- add "r"
{\end{array}\right.}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    TTR(t) = TTR_{PLATEAU} \left( 1 - e^{- k \, t} \right) \text{ con }
    \begin{sistema}
        TTR_{PLATEAU} = \dfrac{ir}{R_a} \\[3ex]
                    k = \dfrac{R_a}{Q} 
    \end{sistema}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I also made some changes:

1. I replaced the long code `\hspace{0.5cm} con \hspace{0.2cm}` with `\text{ con }`,
2. put `[3ex]` after `\\` to add extra vertical space between lines, and
3. changed `\frac` to `\dfrac` (displaystyle fraction).

**Edit**

According to @barbara beeton's comment:
"the spacing before the `=` sign in the image looks incorrect. are you sure that was produced with the `&` before the `=` sign?", there was a bad space produced by `&` so I removed it.

Comment: the spacing before the `=` sign in the image looks incorrect.  are you sure that was produced with the `&` *before* the `=` sign?

Comment: @barbarabeeton You are right. I have not noticed it. I removed it and now it looks correct. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Needless to define a new environment: the `dcases` environment from `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`) does the  job.

Three other possibilities for the alignment of the `=` sign in the system (personally, I find the first solution nicer)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{delarray}

\newcommand{\TTR}{\textit{TTR}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\TTR(t) = \TTR_{\textrm{\tiny PLATEAU}} \bigl( 1 - e^{- k \, t} \bigr) \quad \text{con} \enspace \begin{dcases}
    \TTR_{\textrm{\tiny PLATEAU}} = \frac{ir}{R_a} \\
    k = \frac{R_a}{Q}
  \end{dcases}
\end{equation*}
\bigskip
\begin{empheq}[left = {\TTR(t) = \TTR_{\textrm{\tiny PLATEAU}} \bigl( 1 - e^{- k \, t} \bigr) \quad \text{con} \enspace\empheqlbrace}]{align*}
    \TTR_{\textrm{\tiny PLATEAU}} & = \smash[t]{\frac{ir}{R_a}} \\[0.5ex]
    k & = \frac{R_a}{Q}
\end{empheq}
\bigskip

\begin{equation*}
\TTR(t) = \TTR_{\textrm{\tiny PLATEAU}} \bigl( 1 - e^{- k \, t} \bigr) \quad \text{con} \enspace \begin{dcases}\begin{aligned}
    \TTR_{\textrm{\tiny PLATEAU}} & = \frac{ir}{R_a} \\[0.5ex]
    k & = \frac{R_a}{Q}
\end{aligned}
  \end{dcases}
\end{equation*}
\bigskip

\begin{equation*}
\TTR(t) = \TTR_{\textrm{\tiny PLATEAU}} \bigl( 1 - e^{- k \, t} \bigr) \quad \text{con} \enspace \begin{array}\{{@{}r@{{}={}}l@{}}. 
    \TTR_{\textrm{\tiny PLATEAU}} & \dfrac{ir}{R_a} \\[2ex]
    k & \dfrac{R_a}{Q}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think (though I'm not entirely sure) that one of the OP's objectives was to align the two `=` symbols inside the "sistema". Any suggestions for how to achieve this within the `dcases` framework? :-)

Comment: Hello @Mico, my goal is to align = symbols inside system of equations. Is possible to do it with your code?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi -- Does the second form, "sistemax", help achieve your goal?

Comment: @Mico Yes, it's the right way.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi: I've added 3 other solutions, with alignment of the equal signs.